# Is running a browser as group via sudo dangerous?

Tags: firefox, sudo, gui, browser, groups

Suppose that `internet` is a group I have created. Is it dangerous to run e.g. Firefox via `sudo -g internet firefox`? I am 99% sure it's not, but wanted to make sure since I am doing that often and I read that running GUIs as root (via `sudo`) is dangerous (I assume since someone exploiting a weakness in the GUI could use root rights on my PC if I am running the GUI as root).

Comment: It is 100% dangerous and makes no sense at all.

Comment: Could you elaborate why it is dangerous? And my motivation for using it in the first place is because I only want apps to be able to access the network that are run from group `internet` (I am using iptables to only allow apps run as `internet` to access the network).

Comment: If you give these apps root permissions, they can do everything with your system. That's a really bad idea.

Comment: Am I giving them root permission even if internet is a non-root group? Also, as additional information, I am running `sudo -g internet firefox` as a non-root user (the user can use sudo in this case due to permission via /etc/sudoers. And thank you for your quick answers! :)

Comment: Is the purpose of this activity to allow a snappified Firefox to read outside of a home directory? 

Comment: No, it's actually to help me fight procrastination. The idea is that I allow only explicitly white-listed apps to access the internet (which I can't change without my sudo password, which I don't know from memory and I keep stashed away during working hours). I can also only run firefox with certain locked settings and profile.

Comment: The idea is actually to have it such that I can't browse the internet freely except if I know my sudo password (I sadly have EXTREMELY poor self-discipline, so a minor inconvenience wouldn't stop me). Of course, even my current settings could surely be bypassed, but for now, I don't (and don't want to) know and if I do, I just add an additional layer to my anti-procrastination settings. I also don't know what you mean with dock and the .desktop file (I am not that advanced with Ubuntu/Linux).

Comment: Anyway, while I appreciate the discussion, I would appreciate it if someone could answer my question in my earlier comment i.e. "Am I giving them root permission even if `internet` is a non-root group? Also, as additional information, I am running `sudo -g internet firefox` as a non-root user (the user can use sudo in this case due to permission via /etc/sudoers. And thank you for your quick answers! :)". The comment section seems to be deviating from my original question and if the final answer is that running the browser the way I currently am isn't dangerous, my problem would be solved :D

Comment: @Pilot6 With `sudo -g`, if you don't set a user with `-u`, it just runs as the invoking user, not root, so it should be safe. (e.g., `sudo -g some-group id` should show your user's username and UID in the output)

Comment: Just confirmed what @muru wrote. Also, I tried to download a file to the /bin folder while running firefox as `sudo -g internet firefox`, but couldn't due to missing write access. I assume this proves that I don't have root rights, since otherwise, I would have been able to download a file to /bin?

Comment: Running graphical applications with `sudo` is never a good idea because `sudo` in setting up the environment does not account for running graphical applications.

Comment: @vanadium Do you mean that the environment variables get changed? I have just checked that and they do indeed change. However, does that introduce any risks?

Comment: Yes. Wrong file permissions may be set on files in your home directory.

Comment: I see, I will look into that. Thank you!